# Unity blur material makes everything black with LWRP

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, shader, blur

In unity I was using a blur material in my canvas so that the background is not visible clearly. But I had to use LWRP now for some things I was using in other games before.

The old Blur effect clearly did not work anymore so I tried different Blurs like the one from this asset:
https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/vfx/shaders/blur-lightweight-146235

This worked great in a Testproject but I do not get it to work in my current Project. I added it to an image but the whole panel background gets black. I have set the LWRP, graphic as well as the camera configs to the same as in the Testproject but it still was black. Anyone knows why this could be?

How it looks in Testproject:
[image]

How it looks in the main Project:
[image]

**Ps:** I am also getting an error sometimes which says something like:
`Material doesn't have a texture property '_MainTex'`

Comment: You're gonna need to share that material and the script that is controlling it for us to investigate thoroughly. Though be aware if you're allowed to... if not then it'll be difficult.  I just checked out the link to asset store. It should work with LWRP as it's made for it. Seems like something is not set up properly so more info on that front iwll be relevant.

Comment: I can tell you what that error is coming from. There's script somewhere (prob will open if you double click the error) which is trying ti access the main texture of the material which doesn't exist in the shader/material.

Comment: @user14492 ye the error seems to appear because the shader does not work so it does not create a main Texture. I put a link in my question, thats a shader i have tested already. These shader works by getting the Texture from the main camera (by the reference _CameraOpaqueTexture) but it seems to no working.

Comment: I have found a workaround for now ... I am creating a cub and adding the material to it. I make the cube to a flat tarp and place it infront of the cam...

Comment: I am having issue. Can you post the shader you are using? The asset link is not working now

Comment: @SaadAnees I dont know if I still have this project on my pc but I will post about it when I am home and have time :D

Comment: @SaadAnees I am very sorry but even though I found my old project It will not run anymore because of t he newer Unity Versions. ALl my materials and shaders are outdated and I currently do niot really have the time to get behind thois and fix it :/